# BLE triangulation

Tags: bluetooth, synchronization, bluetooth-lowenergy, triangulation

I'm thinking about starting a new project in my company regarding indoor positioning using bluetooth.

The main idea is to have a place (think a museum) mapped, and have it covered with beacons, in a manner that every spot will be covered by at least 3 signals.
The beacons are fixed and they would only transmit something like `XPT001112222` where `XPT` is the beacon ID and the rest is the current second+millisecond+microsecond+asPreciseAsICanGet "transmission" time. A enabled device would read that package, and by time-displacement, a device would calculate it's distance from a beacon, and calculating from 3, ok we have a position... something like the GPS...

What scares me here is the time precision... how can i work that variable out? I mean, how can I figure out how much time the app spent from actually receiving the package until actually getting the current date? because, if i miss that window by lets say ins, i get a foot wrong...

Comment: Look in the Bluetooth LE specs...  there are components for time synchronization.  Unfortunately I don't remember exactly where.  I just remember there's somewhere that a device can report how accurate it's internal clock is (how much it can possibly drift).

Comment: GPS satellites use precise and synchronised (to whithin a few nanoseconds) atomic clocks, which is why I think this might prove to be a difficult task for BLE.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this won't *fully* answer your question, but
did you think about using the signal-strength-indicator?

I'm not perfectly sure about the possible accuracy, but I think its a much better way,
since the signal-strength-calculation is done on a much lower layer/directly in hardware.

With pure software (on a Smartphone, without any real-time requirements!) I don't think you'll get accurate enough.

Comment: RSSI isn't a good determinator of distance, especially in an environment that might have something in it other than emptiness. Even if you have calibrated beacons broadcasting at a known strength, RSSI isn't defined or calibrated across different devices - it's just a scalar value. So you'd have to do a calibration for every handset. Having it broadcast it's RSSI value of your device is worse because mobile platforms vary broadcast strength opaquely.

Comment: Shouldn't it work when all beacons send their RSSI value of the device together with a hash of the devices MAC/UUID? (saved for X seconds internally) Then the Device simply asks all available beacons for their RSSI value of $device and should have the differences in strength. Unless the device changes broadcasting strength every few seconds, this should work IMHO. (I Agree that anything between device&beacon still can be a problem)